# Best way to redirect root domain ("apex domain") to another location

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, cname-record, amazon-route53

This question is a continuation of [Using Route53 to point apex/root domain to Heroku application](https://serverfault.com/questions/759870/using-route53-to-point-apex-root-domain-to-heroku-application)

Right now I have my domain abc.com registered with Route53. I am using a ddns service to point it to a home server setup. Because of CNAME limitations I can only do this on sub-domains which is usually all I use it for (while hosting the root domain on the cloud). Right now I want to redirect abc.com to [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) in the simplest/cheapest way possible using AWS. There are so many tools on the platform, it's hard to know which one to use for a simple task!

Answer (score 3):

This ended up being pretty simple using the technique described here https://devopslife.io/redirect-a-route53-domain-to-another-domain-using-s3/:

> Create an S3 bucket with the name of domain “example.org”
> Please note that S3 bucket names must be globally unique. If the bucket name you need is already taken, you can’t use S3 for
> redirection and this documentation won’t be applicable for you. You
> may use other work arounds like redirection using a webserver in
> backend.
> Go to properties and select “Static web hosting”
> From the dropdown, select Redirect all requests to another host name.
> Enter example.com here and protocol (HTTP or HTTPS) and save it
> Go to Route53 and select the hosted zone for example.org
> Create a record for example.org with the below values
>
> Record Type: A – IPv4 address
>
> Alias: Yes Alias
>
> Target: Choose your S3
> bucket under the heading "S3 Website Endpoints"
>
> Routing Policy: Simple
> Evaluate Health Target: No
>
> Record Type: A – IPv4 address
> Alias: Yes Alias
>
> Target: Choose your S3 bucket under the heading "S3 Website Endpoints"
>
> Routing Policy: Simple Evaluate Health Target: No

Comment: Amazon API Gateway can be configured as a proxy service to handle any kind of redirection. It seems like all available options include an extra layer of redirection.